# Remove the messages from elasticsearch whe a log is updated

Tags: csv, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I am using ELK stack to monitor some changes in a `csv` file. The `csv` file is updated in time interval. So that the rows can be updated or deleted. Currently `logstash`. As an Example, if we have 10 rows in the `csv` file at 10.15 am. It may be 6 rows at 10.30 am and again 20 rows at 11.00 am.

Existing rows are updated in `Elasticsearch` as well using following configuration.

```
input {
    file {
        path => "D:\Projects\A\Installations\logstash\logstash-2.3.4\bin\code.txt"
        start_position => beginning
    }
}
filter {
    csv {
        columns => [
        "A", 
        "B",
        "C", 
        "D"
        ]
        separator => ","
        }
    mutate{
        convert => {
        "B" => "integer"
        "C" => "integer"
        "D" => "integer"
        }
        }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
    hosts=>["localhost:9200"]
    index => "report"
    document_id => "%{A}"
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

The problem is when a row gets deleted. It is not reflected in `Elasticsearch` and therefore in kibana.

So, could these type of situations be handled from logstash configuration file?

Comment: Can you paste your some sample from your csv file? Also Have you checked for Logstash and Elasticsearch logs? Posting more information will be helpful.

Comment: `A,B,C,D
Comp1,1,5,8
Comp2,75,45,52
Comp3,40,20,45
Comp4,4,23,80
Comp5,80,23,12`

Hope this helps